# How to fix ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to use Geocoder for some things, but it is not working anymore, it had already worked but is now giving this error:
ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined

I am using version 6.0.8 of Angular and @types/googlemaps3.30.20

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
declare let google: any;
...
public geoCoder: any;
...

ngOnInit(){
    this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
}
```

and the browser error is this:
ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined

I found it strange, because I had done this project, I left working and now that I came back to make some changes is not working anymore, and I'm already a few days out of place because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it because the Google API is not loaded yet and you are trying to access it.

```
ngOnInit(){
    if(google) this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
}
```

And install:

```
npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

Comment: @VictorEzequiel did you `install npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev` ?

Comment: Yes, I also put "googlemaps" on "types" in the files: tsconfig.app.json, tsconfig.spec.json and in tsconfig.json on "typeRoots" put "node_modules/@types", "types", "googlemaps"

Comment: thanks for helping, but i solve this changing my internet, i don't now how, but today I decided to test with a different connection and it worked out, thanks!